# How to open 2 Adobe Reader instances?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

I would like to see simultaneously pages in the beginning of the document and at the end. I can do that by opening the same document on different windows. But when I try to do so, the first instance opens and I can't open a second one. I'll will install a second PDF visualizer to do it, but I wonder if I could do something that didn't require such extreme measure.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://superuser.com/a/314693/201359) answer way better than the currently accepted one?

Comment: For Linux users: Evince can do this as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/123843/173666

Comment: I feel like the title of this post should be edited to "How to open the same document in 2 Adobe Reader windows."  Opening a new window instead of a second instance of Adobe Reader accomplishes what the OP wanted to do, but other users may actually want to open two instances of the application for other reasons, and they won't find how to do that in the accepted answer.  For example, I want to open two instances of Acrobat Pro DC, because when one is performing "recognize text" on a document, it ties up the entire application. For example, you can't view or edit another file.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just go to the upper menu and click "Window">"New Window".

[image: Easy]

Then you'll have two instances of one document opened in separate windows.

Answer (score 10):

You could make a (temporary) copy of the PDF in question, with a different name, and then open them both in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 3):

In Reader 20145.010.20060 you can simple drag and drop from the tab in the Reader window and another window will appear

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can do this with Adobe Acrobat, but sadly, not Reader.   I'd go ahead and download Foxit anyways. Or CutePDF.

Comment: Or Google Chrome. :)

Comment: Or SumatraPDF or any other listed in http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-reader/

Comment: The New Window option worked for me in Reader X.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 13.04.  `File` -> `Open` a new copy or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> opens a new instance of the same PDF file. This is helpful when you are answering chapter end Q&A so you don't have to go back and forth.

Comment: Ctrl+N is just the keyboard shortcut for `Window` -> `New Window`, right?

Comment: Are we still talking about Adobe Reader here?

Answer (score 1):

Start the second Acrobat Reader instance, then in the second instance open the same document using menu "File".

To start the second instance make a copy of Acrobat Reader shortcut, open properties of copied shortcut, choose "Shortcut" tab and add " /n" at the end of Target field. For example, if original Target field value is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
```

modified value must be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n
```

Every time modified shortcut is started a new independent Acrobat Reader instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative solution:

If I want to open a pdf file twice, I usually open a pdf using a pdf reader and then I open the same pdf file using a web-browser (i.e Firefox).